# soundcloud could not get email

Tags: php, jquery, soundcloud

i am using soundcloud login php script i could not get email value below ic my code

```
$soundcloud = new Services_Soundcloud($clientId, $clientSecret, $callback);
try {
   $accessToken = $soundcloud->accessToken($_GET['code']);
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
try {
    $me = json_decode($soundcloud->get('me'), true);
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}

$user_data = array(
                'access_token' => $accessToken['access_token'],
                'id' => $me['id'],
                'username' => $me['username'],
                'name' => $me['full_name'],
                'email' => $me['email'],
                'avatar' => $me['avatar_url']
            );

print_r($user_data );
```

value of email is blank how can i get it please tell

Array ( [id] => 141963337 [kind] => user [permalink] => gaurav-kumar-mishra-1 [username] => Gaurav Kumar Mishra [last_modified] => 2015/03/07 02:33:49 +0000 [uri] => https://api.soundcloud.com/users/141963337 [permalink_url] => http://soundcloud.com/gaurav-kumar-mishra-1 [avatar_url] => https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-000134585606-t4nmub-large.jpg [country] => [first_name] => Gaurav [last_name] => Kumar Mishra [full_name] => Gaurav Kumar Mishra [description] => [city] => [discogs_name] => [myspace_name] => [website] => [website_title] => [online] => [track_count] => 0 [playlist_count] => 0 [plan] => Free [public_favorites_count] => 0 [followers_count] => 0 [followings_count] => 0 [subscriptions] => Array ( ) [upload_seconds_left] => 10800 [quota] => Array ( [unlimited_upload_quota] => [upload_seconds_used] => 0 [upload_seconds_left] => 10800 ) [private_tracks_count] => 0 [private_playlists_count] => 0 [primary_email_confirmed] => 1 )

Comment: What contains in `$me` variable ?

Comment: Can you show `print_r($me)` ?

Comment: I can't find email in your `$me` variable. How can you access ?

Comment: If there is no any field named `email` exist then how can you retrieve ?

Comment: Sorry! I dont know what is soundcloud ?

Answer (score 1):

Its not a part of the me-endpoint.

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#me